# "Mauve" screen on startup (Old Intel Mac)

Tags: boot, system-installation, mac

Trying to get latest Ubuntu running on an old mac.

Machine boots from the USB, slowly goes through a file system check, then boots Ubuntu.

There is a chime (which I guess means Ubuntu is loaded) but the screen is mauve/purple and nothing else appears to happen after about a 20+ minute wait.

Only reason for booting into Ubuntu is to do a full install (in case that influences your response).

Anyone got any ideas as to where to look and how to resolve this?  Machine is too good to just throw away.

Comment: Are you sure this !old mac! can run the latest Ubuntu? What ever that may be many versions can be called the latest. Try running a version more suited to the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than delete the question I'll leave it here for the benefit of others.

Some 45 minutes after the initial boot the install/try screen finally showed up and I am now installing (I hope).